# Am I doing something wrong when I open/close my windows?

Tags: c#, wpf, window

I've noticed a troubling behavior in the windows that I open in my application:  commands and (most noticeably) their "can execute" methods, are firing long after the window itself has been closed.

Here's a reduced example of how I tend to do things:

```
public class AllMaxThemedWindow : DevExpress.Xpf.Core.ThemedWindow, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public static DependencyProperty ShowMinimizeButtonProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ShowMinimizeButton", typeof(Boolean), typeof(AllMaxThemedWindow), new PropertyMetadata(true));
    public Boolean ShowMinimizeButton
    {
        get => (Boolean)GetValue(ShowMinimizeButtonProperty);
        set => SetValue(ShowMinimizeButtonProperty, value);
    }
    //Maximize and Close DPs as well

    public AllMaxThemedWindow()
    {
        Loaded += AllMaxThemedWindow_Loaded;
    }

    private void AllMaxThemedWindow_Loaded(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!ShowMinimizeButton)
        {
            var button = (Button)DevExpress.Xpf.Core.Native.LayoutHelper.FindElementByName(this, DXWindow.ButtonParts.PART_Minimize.ToString());
            button.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        //Maximize and Close checks as well

        //If neither maximize nor minimize is allowed, then prevent the system menu from being shown (via button or right-click).
        if (!ShowMaximizeButton && !ShowMinimizeButton)
        {
            var hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
            NativeMethods.SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, NativeMethods.GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE) & ~WS_SYSMENU);
        }
    }
}

<atw:AllMaxThemedWindow x:Class="Antero.Windows.ThemedWindowInstance">
    <atw:AllMaxThemedWindow.DataContext>
        <vm:ThemedWindowInstanceViewModel />
    </atw:AllMaxThemedWindow.DataContext>
</atw:AllMaxThemedWindow>

//...opened this way in a view model's button command handler
new ThemedWindowInstance().ShowDialog(true);
```

Beyond that, nothing special is happening.  It's just a `Window` ultimately, and that window is opened as modal.  Then the user clicks the `X` to close it.

That's when the bad things happen.  For example, on one window there is a `Save` button, and that button is bound to a command (in its view model) that has a "can execute" method.  That method will continue to be fired long after the window has been closed.  It just seems to fire forever, in fact.

I came from the WinForms world, so I'm used to doing things like `Dispose`, but that doesn't seem to be available to me in WPF.  So what is it in the WPF world that leaves a window (or its view model) hanging out in limbo forever?

Comment: Is there some other view bound to the same view model? How do you set the DataContext? The sample code you have posted is incomplete.

Comment: @mm8 It's just set in the XAML, and no, everything is 1:1 as I'm doing it.

Comment: Please provide more context code. Show us the commands, the view-models, how do you create bindings, how do you wire-up view-models with views etc.

Comment: @dymanoid That will be an enormous amount of code, hence the stripped-down examples.  If you can be precise about what you want to know, I could try to provide very specific examples of that.  Otherwise, you're asking a lot.

Comment: How can we help if you cannot provide a [mcve]? It's impossible to guess what is wrong. The fact is, there are some references kept alive. Either create a sample that demonstrates your approach and the issue, or use a memory profiler to find out the zombie references and spot the code why they are still alive.

Comment: Your viewmodel is a private member of the window. The window should be garbage collected and it's vm along with it. Which means something is retaining a reference to that window. Showdialog calls close when they hit the x and that disposes that window.  Unless something keeps it alive. Do you have anything like a timer you're using in there?

Comment: Why is your window implementing inotifypropertychanged when you have a viewmodel?

Comment: @Andy There are no timers or anything static.  The property changed is there so that any inheritors of the window class have it available to them, as they won't always have a view model.  I've added an example of a DependencyProperty that the base window class uses.

Comment: DPs do not rely on inpc.

Comment: You could download a free trial of redgate ants profiler and point it at your app. It'll probably tell you what's keeping a reference to your stuff.

Answer (score -1):

Your ICommand implementation should implement CanExecuteChanged event. And you should fire this event each time the execution condition actually changes. Ususally the ICommand implementation has a NotifyCanExecuteChanged method.

```
public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute = null;
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute = null;

    #region Constructors

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null) { }

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    #endregion

    #region ICommand Members

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute != null ? _canExecute(parameter) : true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_execute != null)
            _execute(parameter);
    }

    public void NotifyCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        if(CanExecuteChanged != null)
            CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    #endregion

}
```

Comment: Not to dispute your statement...but what does this have to do with the question I am asking?